# How to get updated variable from my Thread countdown time class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, libgdx

Hi I have been trying to make a simple 10 second countdown timer for my libgdx game for hours now but I keep running into problems.  I am now running the countdown timer in a separate class which implements runnable.  This class works perfectly and it counts down the time as planned, I have ran a system.out.println within this thread to verify it working.  The problem is printing/drawing this timer variable in my main game screen.

If I try to print this variable from my game screen I get the starting variable of it i.e. ten rather than the constantly updating one(counting down from ten).  I have even used a getter method with still no luck.  Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks

I am assuming this is because the Thread is running parallel to the main game?

```
public class timekeep implements Runnable {
public Boolean TimerRunning=true;
private int Timer = 10; //need to print this from my main game screen as it changes

    public void run() {
    while(TimerRunning == true) {
            System.out.println("Time left "+ Timer);//works perfectly prints countdown
            //run code 
            //subtracts 1 from Timer every second
        }
    }

    public int gettime(){
        return Timer;//returns timer
    }
}
....

//accessing Timer variable from main game
System.out.println(Timekeep.gettime());//prints 10 all the time in the main screen
```

Comment: Your example is very incomplete. We can't get to see the TimeKeep.gettime method.  Also I don't see any place that Timer is changed. So it's not surprising that it doesn't change.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to post my entire thread class, I wanted to keep my code as simple and relevant as possible.  My thread class works its just that I cannot access the constantly updating variable Timer from my main game.    It always outputs 10 from there.   When the thread runs it subtracts 1 from Timer every second I see this working fine within my Thread system.out.println just not my main game.

Comment: Presumably you have only one object of class timeKeep and you use that to initialize a new thread which is then started.  Your class is not thread safe. I would suggest that you do declare `TimerRunning` and `Timer` as `volatile` or protect them with synchronization. This might not fix your problem, but it can't hurt to make your class thread safe.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that

Comment: I made my TimerRunning and Timer variables volatile but still no luck.

Comment: Well at least you know that's not the problem.  Now, do you know that the Timekeep object is the same as the one that the thread is based on? And do you know that the the call to gettime is happening after the thread has counted down?

Comment: Timekeep = new timekeep();
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new timekeep());
  t1.start();  I think its the same the one the thread is based on.                                          The call to gettime is happening as the Thread is counting down in my main game render method.  A system.out.println to the log shows this.

Comment: Well your code executes two `new timekeep()` expressions and so two objects are created. You need to recode so that only one `timekeep` object is created.

Comment: Ok thanks I thought that might have been something to do with it but when I keep only Thread t1 = new Thread(new timekeep()); t1.start(); my game freezes then crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code executes two `new timekeep()` expressions and so two objects are created. You need to recode so that only one `timekeep` object is created.  E.g.

```
timekeep theTimeKeeper = new timekeep() ;
Thread t1 = new Thread(theTimeKeeper));
t1.start() ;
... 
System.out.println(theTimeKeeper.gettime());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  However now when I do this the Thread doesn't run.  Any ideas why its stopped running?

Comment: Without seeing the code of the class it is hard to say.  Given the code we can see, the following are possibilities:  (a) that `TimerRunning` is somehow set to false, (b) that there is a `return` from `run`, (c) that there is an exception thrown from `run`, (d) that the thread is interrupted`.

Comment: Ok Thread has just started working again by itself.  Maybe just needed refreshed in eclipse.  I am now going to test if it can print the up to date Timer variable now.Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Again it is not working when I try to get the Timer variable in the timekeep class.  It doesn't like it when I do System.out.println(Timekeep.Timer); or System.out.println(Timekeep.gettime); It just crashes.  I posted my gettime method above does it look wrong?

Comment: No, your gettime method is fine.  I suspect the crashes have nothing to do with the code you've shown. Usually when a Java program crashes there is an exception and a stack trace.  Start with those to figure out what's happening.

Comment: I found out the crash was because I had left an uninstantiated timekeep variable.  However I still have the original problem which is when I call getTimer() it always brings back 10 rather than the countdown version that happens in the Thread.  How would you be calling getTimer() in another class?

Comment: I got something that I wanted working.  I just created a Thread in my main class.  I would rather have created a new class for the Thread but for some reason it wouldn't work.  Thanks for your help